# Adding the Facebook Like Button in my main tableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am working with a nav based app. which parses a feed and displays a tableView. tableView shows titles of all feed items. i want to add a button in the end of the tableView and when user will click that button, it should like the specific facebook group. i already have the FB Connect API integrated into my application. how can i do that like button? thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewCells have an `accessoryView` (and an `accessoryType`). Check out the docs for `UITableViewCell`. You can place a button at the right of your cell as an accessory view.

Highly recommended reading:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

and then:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html